# Show/hide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, click, show-hide

I have one proplem and I hope you guys could help me with it.
Please check my jsfiddle > [myFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyghbzaq/2/)

If you'll click on the 'Details' button you will see the more information about the item with a simple animation.
You can close this details by clicking on the 'cross' icon on the top left corner and you will see the closing animation.

My proplem:
When current item (container) details is opened (and I am not closing details with the 'cross' icon) if I click on other item 'Details' button the first item (container) details did not hide (with the animation).

If someone could help, that would be amazing

Thanks

```
jQuery('.btn.desktop').click(function(){
                jQuery('.btn.desktop.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');

                jQuery('.direction-container.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');


                // If button has class active
                if (jQuery('.btn.desktop').hasClass('active')) {

                    // If button is active add class active to direction container
                    jQuery(this).parent().closest('.direction-container').addClass('active');

                    // If direction container has class active
                    if (jQuery('.direction-container').hasClass('active')) {

                        // Show details container
                        jQuery('.direction-container.active').find('.details-desktop').fadeIn(500);


                        // Scroll down direction container after 500ms
                        setTimeout(function () {    
                            jQuery('.direction-container.active').animate({scrollTop: '100px'}, 500);
                        }, 500);

                        // Show close button
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            jQuery('.direction-container.active').parent().find('.close-details-desktop').fadeIn(500);  
                        }, 1000);



                        // Hide details container
                        jQuery('.direction-container.active').parent().find('.close-details-desktop').click( function() {
                            jQuery('.direction-container.active').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
                            setTimeout(function () {    
                                jQuery('.details-desktop').fadeOut(300);
                                jQuery('.close-details-desktop').fadeOut(500);
                            }, 300);
                            setTimeout(function () {    
                                jQuery('.direction-container, .btn.desktop').removeClass('active');
                            }, 500);
                        });


                    } else {
                    }

                } else {
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not fading them out.

```
jQuery('.direction-container.active').parent().find('.close-details-desktop').click( function() {
```

That only creates a click handler for an active container button. It doesn't trigger a click. Also, it should not be there somewhere deep inside another click handler, as it will only become active after a click on .btn.desktop

Your code is too complex, making it hard for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for reply. To be fair I am a new to javascript. I'll appreciate a lot if you could check my fiddle make correct changes and save it
Please let me know if you could help me with this

Comment: Sure can help you. Do you know how functions work? As that can greatly simplify your code